# Recreate cropping with cropper.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, cropperjs

I am using this plugin https://fengyuanchen.github.io/photo-editor/ to make online photo editor.I am able to save the cropped images on server but how do I recreate that same cropping effect using the same height, width, X and Y used to create that Image on server.If user wants to edit that image.I hope I made my question clear

Comment: Please show us what you tried so far, by creating a [mcve]

Comment: @AlonEitan http://binder.co.in/album/edit/02858cc21d23111cc

Comment: Was able to solve this using this example https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper/blob/master/examples/cropper-in-modal.html